# building boost locale library on Windows

Tags: boost, cmake, locale, building

I am trying to build the boost::locale library (http://cppcms.sourceforge.net/boost_locale/html/tutorial.html#a5771bce93e200c36f7cd9dfd0e5deaa) which is still in review for integration into boost but the cmake command throws up the following:

```
   D:\lib\boost_locale_v2.92\build>cmake ..
-- Looking for ICU libraries
-- Looking for iconv
-- Looking for Boost
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are se
to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake fi
s:
BOOST_THREAD
    linked by target "boost_locale-static" in directory D:/lib/boost_locale_v2
2
ICU_DATA
    linked by target "boost_locale-static" in directory D:/lib/boost_locale_v2
2
ICU_I18N
    linked by target "boost_locale-static" in directory D:/lib/boost_locale_v2
2
ICU_INCLUDE_DIR
   used as include directory in directory D:/lib/boost_locale_v2.92
ICU_UC
    linked by target "boost_locale-static" in directory D:/lib/boost_locale_v2
2

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I have got ICU and boost but can't figure out how to modify the out-of-box cmake script for boost::locale. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Actually these error messages are clear enough. You need to point where is what: boost thread library location, ICU include directory, and others.

Answer (score 0):

Read the installation instructions carefully:

http://cppcms.sourceforge.net/boost_locale/html/building_boost_locale.html

You need to provide:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH=/path/to/boost/include;path/to/icu/include -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/icu/lib ..
```